# How to sort class objects according to user define sorting using arrylist?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

i am sorting class obects  using Comparator in arreyList and i am
getting sorted object according to alphabetically order by name
source of Comparator if below

```
public static Comparator<SortingObjects StuNameComparator = new Comparator<SortingObjects() {

    public int compare(SortingObjects s1, SortingObjects s2) {                 
       String StudentName1 = s1.getName().toUpperCase();                       
       String StudentName2 = s2.getName().toUpperCase();                       
       int c;                                                                  

       c = StudentName1.compareTo(StudentName2);                               



       if(c==0){                                                               
           int rollno1 = s1.getPrice();                                    
           int rollno2 = s2.getPrice();                                    
            c = rollno1-rollno2;                                           
       }                                                                       


       return c;                                                               

    }};
```

and its gives result like:

```
 Student Name Sorting:   


     [ name=AP, price =0]
     [ name=AP, price =0]
     [ name=AP, price =0]
     [ name=AP, price =0]
     [ name=CH, price =0]
     [ name=CH, price =0]
     [ name=CH, price =0]
     [ name=CH, price =0]
     [ name=KE, price =0]
     [ name=KE, price =0]
     [ name=TN, price =0]
```

but i want output like :

```
[ name=CH, price =3]    
   [ name=CH, price =10]
   [ name=AP, price =2] 
   [ name=AP, price =2] 
   [ name=AP, price =7] 
   [ name=AP, price =10]
   [ name=TN, price =15]
   [ name=KE, price =2] 
   [ name=KE, price =5]
```

that means : "CH" comes first then "AP" after that "TN" and at last
"KE" is there any way to implement compare method so that i could get 
result by own define ordering

Comment: your problem seems to be in the `SortingObject` class and not the comparison itself, since the output only shows `price=0`. You might want to include this class for us in order to find the problem.

Comment: With only name or price, there is no way to sort like you want, afterall it doesn't follow any order.

Comment: What type of ordering you are looking for? your ask does not define any order.

Comment: Don't use subtraction to compare ints (e.g. `c = rollno1-rollno2;`) - use `Integer.compare`. Subtraction can overflow.

Comment: Have you overriden the equals and hashcode methods in the sortingObjects class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your ordering into array and use it for comparator:

```
public static Comparator<SortingObjects StuNameComparator = new Comparator<SortingObjects() {
    List ordering = Arrays.asList("CH","AP","TN","KE");
    public int compare(SortingObjects s1, SortingObjects s2) {                 

       return ordering.indexOf(s1.name) - ordering.indexOf(s2.name);                                                               

    }};
```

This is just a snippet that how this should like.

Comment: thanx for the help :-)